# Pantheon greeter configuration failed

Tags: greeter, pantheon, hidpi

Here is my `/etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf`:

```
[greeter]
xft-dpi=200
onscreen-keyboard=true
keyboard=onboard
indicators=~language;~a11y;~power
```

No language or a11y indicators, no HiDPI or onboard keyboard.